# Action in Electromagnetism expressed in differential geometry and tensor notation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

$$ S = -\frac{1}{4} \int F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{2} \int F \wedge *F$$

Trying to figure out why this identity holds true and getting stuck.

Comment: This is pretty much the direct application of the definition of the Hodge dual?

Comment: Can you tell us where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: Note, that *tensor notation* expression has an error: the measure of integration is omitted (usually written as $\sqrt{|g|} d^4 x$). This should help.